# Why can we conclude that $F\subset \overline{V}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S_i:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, similarities, that is, applications that have the following property: $d(S_i(x),S_i(y))=r_i\cdot d(x,y)$, for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Given away $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and closure of V ($\overline{V}$), we define
\begin{equation}
\tilde{S}(\overline{V})=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}S_i(\overline{V}).
\end{equation}

If $F=\bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty}\tilde{S}^k(\overline{V})\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. $\tilde{S}^k$ are the iterations, for example, suppose $k=2$, then we have
$\tilde{S}^2(\overline{V})= \bigcup_{(i_1,i_2)\in I_2} (S_{i_1i_2})(\overline{V})$, where $I_2$ is the set of finite sequences with two entries and $S_{i_1i_2}=S_{i_1} \circ S_{i_2}$.
My question is why can we conclude that $F\subset \overline{V}$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is $\overline V$ the topological closure of $V?$

Comment: What do you mean by $\overline{S}^k(\overline{V})$? (particularly I'm asking about the "$k$" on the upper index).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes.

Comment: @SebastiánP.Pincheira Are the iterations, for example, suppose $k=2$, then we have
$S^2(\overline{V})= \bigcup_{(i_1,i_2)\in I_2} (S_{i_1} \circ S_{i_2})(\overline{V})$, where $I_2$ is the set of finite sequences with two entries.

Answer (score 1):

With your definition, you have $F=\bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty}\tilde{S}^k(\overline{V})$. As $\tilde{S}^0(\overline{V}) = \overline{V}$, you automatically get $F \subset \overline{V}$.

If you define $F$ as $F=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\tilde{S}^k(\overline{V})$, then the inclusion is not true in general. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $V = [0,+\infty[ \times \mathbb{R}$, and $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the translations defined by $S_i(x,y) = (x-1,y)$. Then one can see that $S_k(\overline{V}) = [-k,+\infty[\times \mathbb{R}$ and therefore $F = [-1,+\infty[\times \mathbb{R}$ which is not contained in $V = [0,+\infty[ \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why $\tilde{S}^0(\overline{V})=\overline{V}$?

Comment: $\tilde{S}^k(\overline{V})= \bigcup_{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k)\in I_k} (S_{i_1i_2\ldots i_k})(\overline{V})$, where $I_k$ is the set of finite sequences with two entries and $S_{i_1i_2\ldots}=S_{i_1} \circ S_{i_2}\circ \ldots \circ S_{i_k}$.

Comment: If $k=0$, $I_k$ is the empty set. So $S_{\emptyset}(\overline{V})$ is the set obtained when we apply nothing to $\overline{V}$ : this is still $\overline{V}$.

More commonly, if $f:E \to E$ is a map from $E$ to $E$, $f^0$ is the identity map of $E$.